# Delay css position change with pure css

Tags: html, css

With the CSS3 transition-delay Property I can delay the opacity, color etc.

**But how can I delay things like the position with pure css ?**

```
.element{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

// Delay with 1s 

    .demo--active .element{
        position: relative;
        visibility: visible;
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to acheivee here it's hard to offer alternative solutions. Perhaps you could demo the issue preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check out CSS animation keyframes!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to actually animate between the position values eg: from static to absolute- then you can't! - because `position` is not an animatable property.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> Animatable    no

**However** if you just want to delay the change between the values - this can be done with the `animation-delay` and `animation-fill-mode` properties:

### [Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QNLpao?editors=1100)

```css
.wpr {
  position: relative;
}
.wpr div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
.wpr div:nth-child(3) {
  animation: test 2s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes test {
  from {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Notice (from the above demo) that:

1) there's a 3s delay for the 3rd div to change to `position:absolute`

2) With `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` we can ensure that the animated block will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe.

Comment: That's a great solution, but it doesn't seem to work in safari. It ignores the position-state and stays with position: static. Is there a workaround for that?